# How to display multiple calendar icon calendar events using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-rest-api

I would like to view a sharepoint calendar using this view [here](https://ibb.co/bvyw15V)

Happy to do it using rest or CSOM but looking for a jquery plugin.
Anyone done something similar or where can i find such a plugin.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: SharePoint Online

Comment: Where do you want to show this? On Page? If you want to show in the list itself then in classic experience you can use JSLink and in modern experience, you can use view formatting. To show on page, maybe you can create SPFx webpart.

Comment: Its a Classic not modern.. Thanks anyway i have put some custom one together using JS,CSS and HTML

Comment: In case of classic, you can use JSLink or custom solution using SharePoint REST/JSOM to pull the data from list and HTML, CSS to show it in desired user experience. Have you managed to do that?